# get all variable names from a string javascript

Tags: javascript

```
string = 'a="1";b="5";d="4";';
```

I want to get all variables inside a string. I'm making a javascript validator that will fetch all variables inside my given variable..

output should be

```
output = ["a","b","d"];
```

Comment: Will the variables always come before an `=` like that? Will there be whitespace sometimes? If you're interested in identifying all variables in arbitrary JavaScript code, you need a parser, like [esprima](http://esprima.org/). From their example, `esprima.tokenize` will identify tokens of type `Identifier` which should suit your needs. (`esprima.tokenize(myStr).filter(v=>v.type=="Identifier").map(v=>value)`)

Comment: "*I'm making a javascript validator*" - why do you want to reinvent the wheel? There already are lots of parsers (and linters built on them) out there for JS syntax.

Comment: So did you try anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `string.split(';').map(exp => exp.split('=')[0]).filter(x => x)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var string = 'a="1";b="5";d="4";';
var regexp = /(\w+)=".*?";/g;
var result = [];
var match;
while (match = regexp.exec(string)) {
  result.push(match[1]);
}
console.log(result);
```

You can use a regular expression match:

Answer (score 0):

string.replace(/=[^=]*$/,"").split(/=[^;=]+;/)

Both this answer and the answer involving the map and filter. Will not work if you values contain semi colon or equals characters.

The extra replace in this lets you ignore the last semicolon.

The best way would be to write a parser that counts quotes and ignores anything in the string.